# sed command to write the name of file to HTML comment

Tags: sed

I'm looking for a `sed` command that, with `find`, I can take a directory tree of JSP files and write the name of the file in an HTML comment to the top of the file.

This will allow me to review a legacy application JSP call tree of in the HTML source.

I'm thinking it will be a one liner for a talented `sed` guru...

something like:

`find . -name '.jsp' -exec sed ? ? ? {} \;`

Maybe something using `xargs` is more appropriate, but I think `sed` is the tool that will do the work.

Comment: It was a tough call picking one of these answers... both do the job exactly as desired! Thank you Cristian and Michael!

Comment: You can still upvote my answer and his too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use sed, you can try

```
find -name "*.jsp" -exec sed -i '1i <!-- {} -->' {} \;
```

Works fine for me in the presence of `/`.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking of using the substitute command, not the insert command which doesn't have any problems with `/`.

Comment: You can use characters other than `/` as delimiters in an `s` command in `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix the filename will contain slashes (`/`) which are special characters for sed, so I would recommend this simpler approach that writes the filename at the *bottom* of the file:

```
find . -name '*.jsp' -exec sh -c "echo '<\!-- {} -->' >> '{}'" \;
```

To write the filename at the *top* of the file use this:

```
find . -name '*.jsp' -exec sh -c \
     'echo "<!-- {} -->" > "{}.new" && cat "{}" >> "{}.new" && mv "{}.new" "{}"' \;
```

N.B. The filename might contain characters that might render your HTML invalid, e.g. `&`, although I doubt that a JSP could have such a strange name.

Comment: That will add the comment at the end of the file.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: you're right. I missed that part from the question. I added the solution for the top of the file.